# Getting the value of the checkbox when its unchecked

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm trying to get the value of the checkbox when it's not checked, but it only takes it when it's checked, can anyone help me with it? I need to take the value of **$row[2]** when it's checked and, when unchecked, to give me '*not attended*'.

Thanks. Code below:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
 {          
    echo "<tr><td> "; echo $row[1]; 
    echo "<td> "; echo  $row[0]; 
    echo "<td> "; echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name='check[]' value='".$row[2]."'> </td> ";
    echo "<tr>";
  }
```

Comment: Checkbox gives value only when they are checked. If you want value in every case then make it as hidden.

Comment: How do you extract the row values? Can you posts the form `POST` code?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Sunil in the comments, if you want to retain the original value from the database, your best bet is to add an hidden field to the form.

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{          
    echo "<tr><td> "; echo $row[1]; 
    echo "<td> "; echo  $row[0]; 
    echo "<td> ";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name='check[]' value='".$row[2]."'>"; 
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name='check_original" . $i++ . "' value='".$row[2]."'>"; 
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
```

Now, from your form you have a $_POST['check_originalX'] (where X corresponds to the number of the checkbox) from which you can retrieve the original value.

Comment: Or you use the value or the database row ID as the key for your POST array: `name='check[".$row[2]."]'` or `name='check[".$row[0]."]'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for change type of unchecked input try this :

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {      
        $(this).attr({"type":"text","name":"unchecked[]"});     
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score -2):

If the checkbox is checked, it will contain the assigned value in $_POST. Otherwise you will have to set it when checkbox is unchecked:

```
$value = (isset($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check']) ? $_POST['check'] : "not attended";
```

Or, to expand the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['check']) && !empty($_POST['check'])) {
    $value = $_POST['check'];
} else {
    $value = "not attended";
}
```

**EDIT:** When checking the values in an array, use a `foreach` loop and add the code above for each array item.

Comment: the checkbox is an array so it cant take 'not attended' what can i do ?

Comment: @thinkUP Use it in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: There is no need for a downvote, the code I posted works as expected, provided the OP uses a loop to extract the values.

Comment: if i need to see the $value can u post me the code completly with the echo  $value ? and when i use foreach ?

Comment: when i use foreach it doesnt show the value when the checkbox its unchecked

Answer (score -3):

U can use `isset($_POST['check'][value])` for check PS "value" variable

Comment: This is wrong, you can't get the value of a `$_POST`ed variable like this.

Comment: @Ciprian As I see it this answer is perfectly valid... Obviously `value` is not meant in a literal sense...

Comment: @arkascha The OP is using `name='check[]'` so there really is no way to connect the POST index to a row from the database using just the index. You could using the values but only if the values are unique.

Comment: @arkascha In what sense is `value` meant to be extracted then?

Comment: @jeroen I'd say that depends on what is meant by `value` here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @arkascha That would be a 0-indexed number based on what checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @jeroen Yep, exactly.

Comment: @arkascha You don't know to what checkbox on the form it corresponds, if there are 100 checkboxes and only the 76th is checked, an `isset()` check for `$_POST['check'][0]` will tell you nothing about it really being the 76th.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer has been edited now into the wrong direction...

Comment: @jeroen Yes, obviously you have to evaluate what value that element holds. So I agree that the way this answer is phrased is miss leading. Sorry for the fuzz.

Comment: @arkascha Exactly, so checking if a certain index is set - like in the code above - is pointless, the only way to get useful information is by looping over the ones that are set and check their values.

Comment: @jeroen Which is what I just wrote. Yes.